# How to find Epistemic uncertainty in deep learning model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

The following steps can be used during training

1. Train the model by dropping some selective weights from selective(or each) layer of model.
   e.g. from each Conv2D layer, Drop 20% weights
2. Train the model for best accuracy and minimum loss
3. Again Drop the 20% weights different from the dropped weights in step 1 & allow dropped earlier to train
4. Repeat the process till all weights are dropped one time

During Prediction
Randomly drop some weights in the model and make predictions. This step can be repeated many times (Let it be repeated 3 times)
Now measure the deviation among the predictions
(in case of classification ---> Deviation between the predicted probabilities are measured
in case of regression problem ---> Deviation can be measured from the predicted results)
Lower the deviation, Higher is the uncertainty and vice versa

How can we implement the idea using tensorflow and python

Comment: Why not ask the lecturer? They are paid for this, you know.